# Delete an entity in EF when its FK is cleared

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Use the following model as an example:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int? ScanId { get; set; }
    public Scan Scan { get; set; }
}

public class Scan
{
    public int ScanId { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I've associated an instance of `Scan` to an instance of `Item`.  If I disassociate the `Scan` record, I want to know if there is a way to configure EF such that it would automatically delete the orphaned `Scan` record.  I believe the concept of cascading deletes does not apply to this situation because it would only pertain to deleting a `Scan` record if it's `Item` record was deleted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can associate a [ForeignKey('ScanID')] in Item , so that when you deleting Scan, it will delete from Item too

Comment: You can't with the shown design. FK cascades from source to target (the one who is referencing it), not the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

How about overriding `SaveChanges()`? You could check for the modified Item entities, check whether originally the ScanId was not null and now it is null, get the Scan entity for the original ScanId, and then remove it. Something like this:

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
 {
   List<int> orphanedScanIds = new List<int>();
   foreach (var item in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.Entity is Item && e.State == EntityState.Modified))
   {
      var original = (int?)item.OriginalValues[nameof(Item.ScanId)];
      var current = (int?)item.CurrentValues[nameof(Item.ScanId)];
      if (original.HasValue && !current.HasValue)
      {
          orphanedScans.Add(original.Value);
      }
   }
   var orphanedScans = this.Scans.Where(s => orphanedScans.Contains(s.ScanId)).ToList();
   foreach (var orphanedScan in orphanedScans)
   {
      this.Scans.Remove(orphanedScan);
   }
   return base.SaveChanges();
 }
```